# Short list won't repeat in together loop in ansible-task

Tags: loops, nested-loops, ansible

I've got this Ansible-playbook:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
    - name: test nested loops
      shell: echo "a={{ item.0 }} b={{ item.1 }}"
      with_together:
         - [ 'vol1', 'vol2', 'vol3', 'vol4', 'vol5']
         - [ 'cmp01', 'cmp02', 'cmp03']
```

Currently I get this result:

```
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol1', 'cmp01'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol2', 'cmp02'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol3', 'cmp03'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol4', None])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol5', None])
```

Instead of this result, I want the last list to repeat itself.

```
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol1', 'cmp01'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol2', 'cmp02'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol3', 'cmp03'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol4', 'cmp01'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol5', 'cmp02'])
```

This is a short example playbook but it holds a lot of possibilities. This is because I want to use this to delegate `VOL1` to `CMP01`, etc.

**Remark:** I cannot use nested loops because then I get this:

```
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol1', 'cmp01'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol1', 'cmp02'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol1', 'cmp03'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol2', 'cmp01'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol2', 'cmp02'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol2', 'cmp03'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol3', 'cmp01'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol3', 'cmp02'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol3', 'cmp03'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol4', 'cmp01'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol4', 'cmp02'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol4', 'cmp03'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol5', 'cmp01'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol5', 'cmp02'])
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=['vol5', 'cmp03'])
```

Even when I include a `run_once: true` option, it does not work, which is pretty logic.

**Ansible-documentation:** http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Ansible provides a `with` loop that will do exactly what you're looking for.  Your best option may be to write your own [custom loop iterator](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#writing-your-own-iterators) that behaves exactly as you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see in [Ansible source for with_together](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/together.py) There is no support for what you are asking. You have two options. Write your own lookup_plugin (recommended) or patch your ansible install (may have some side effect) to accomplish what you are asking for.

```
"""
Transpose a list of arrays:
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] -> [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]
Replace any empty spots in 2nd array with None:
[1, 2], [3] -> [1, 3], [2, None]
"""
```

Comment: Where do you see that in the source? A link to GitHub would be useful. Also an example of how to do what the OP is asking for or something similar would make this a good answer.